# Blazor, windows account and AzureAD/Microsoft Identity Platform login automatic?

Tags: blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

If I create a new Blazor server application, choose to use Microsoft Identity Platform and connect to our work.

When I run that application without any changes, my windowsaccount log in and my name/mailadress at work shows on top on screen.

I have an old project where I got this behavior before but last week the project doesn't logged in with my workaccount automatic anymore, I need to push login button and then my Blazor server app login in with my workaccount automatic.

What I know I haven't change any code that connect to AzureAD last week. What code is it in a fresh Blazor Server application that are configure with Microsoft Identity Platform that make an automatic login if you are logged in with a microsoft account on your computer?

My Program.cs that don't login automatic anymore.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("role", "Admin"));
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

..

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();  

builder.Services.AddControllers();// Add support for API controllers
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Blazor API V1");
    });
}

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();  

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```